# iOS 9.2.1 Getting webView:didFailLoadWithError - 102: Frame load interrupted in Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm in the middle of a project for iOS, where I after upgrading to iOS 9.2.1 on my iPhone, have problems.

I have successfully used OpenFB in my Phonegap app (http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/), but after upgrading to iOS 9.2.1, I only got an empty window with black bar in the buttom, where I can click on "Done".

Log says:

> webView:didFailLoadWithError - 102: Frame load interrupted

I'm I the only one seeing this problem? I got an iPad with iOS 9.2 where it works like charm.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar`, change it with `cordova-plugin-statusbar`:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" />
```